# Code for Variations with repetition (combinatorics) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, combinatorics

Does anyone have Javascript code for generating all variations with repetition?

Example of variations with repetition:

```
(size=3, input=A,B)
AAA, AAB, ABA, BAA, ABB, BAB, BBA, BBB
```

What I need is to do something similar for numbers from 0-9 as the input and 6 digits length as size (according to my example).

Just to know, I got this working with a code in Java and also in .NET based on this project (check the link). All variations with repetition for what I need generates 1000000 values.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx

Is it possible to do it in Javascript?

Comment: It's just two for loops: one for position, one for letter, any reasonable language can do that.

Comment: @trutheality Is not so simple as just two loops (in my opinion) that's why I am here :-)

Comment: Every algorithm can be expressed in JavaScript. jQuery won't be of any help here.

Comment: The numbers answer with one loop looks good to me :) Just how complex is your Java and .NET code?

Comment: Here's a working code based on Soufiane's code below which give you 1000000 repetitions http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/TFhvD/ like .Net and java for your desired setup

Comment: Thank you for all your contributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have chosen the simplest case from combinatorics...

```
var i, n = 1000000;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  console.log(('' + (i + n)).substring(1));
```

will give you all the combinations of 0-9 in 6 spots (1000000 === `Math.pow(10, 6)`).

Answer (score 1):

I've just wrote it right now, it needs more tests and optimizations but this should get you started:

```
​var input = "ABCD";
var size = 3;
var results = [];

function solve(i, elt) {
    if(elt.length == size) { 
       results.push(elt);
       return;        
    }
    for(var j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
       solve(j, elt+input[j]);
    }        
}​​​​​​

solve(0, "");
​console​.log(results);​
```

Comment: Nice code, the problem is for some reason that when using input="0123456789"; and size = 6; the results.length is: 5005 and in the .NET and Java code the results are 1000000.

Comment: aha! thanks Joy, I didn't get that, I assumed somehow that the OP needed the order to be preserved

Comment: Sorry, added that comment above on question :)